# A button in a window with graphics

Tags: android

I'd like to know how to create buttons, textViews etc. in an Activity, which doesn't use an xml file as ContentView.

What I mean:

Main Class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
//...
puzzleView = new PuzzleView(this);
setContentView(puzzleView);
}
```

The PuzzleView class:

```
public class PuzzleView extends View
{
    private final Game game;

    public PuzzleView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.game = (Game) context;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
    // drawing some things here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set your content view to a class that extends  [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), then add views to that class. [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) are probably what you're after, in particular. Here are some tutorials:

http://blogspot.arcintechnologies.com/android/generate-android-layout-programmatically/

http://mainerrors.blogspot.ca/2011/02/programmatically-creating-layout-part-1.html